# Is there a method for recalculating/updating the bounding rect of an object in fabric.js?

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to make a modifiable cubic bezier curve in fabric.js.
The problem I have now is that when I update the curve by dragging the control points, the bounding rectangle of the curve will not update.

I have some (ugly) code here:
http://codepen.io/andershj/pen/PbwqzX?editors=1000

As you can see from the example, the bounding rect will not update after updating the curve.

Is there a method for updating/recalculating the bounding rect?

```
...
canvas.on({
   'object:modified' : onObjectModified
});

function onObjectModified(e) {
    canvas.setActiveObject(e.target.line.curve);
    // Is there a method to recalculate the bounding rect when object is modified?
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky but you can solve it like this:

```
function onObjectModified(e) {
  e.target.line.curve.pathOffset = null;
  e.target.line.curve._setPositionDimensions({});
  canvas.setActiveObject(e.target.line.curve);
}
```